Gwt Atmosphere 1 Million long polling requests per hour
We have currently the problem, that our gwt web application is sending 1 million long-polling atmosphere calls per hour to the tomcat, when you have it opened.
They are answered directly with 200 and with empty response body.
We have a scheduler, that triggers the push every 60 seconds to refresh the data in the client.
Still, the long-polling is not waiting for the push.
We have a similar application where it is working with the same configuration.
Can it be a problem with a tomcat configuration or some authentication configuration problem?
Did someone had a similar issue?
Example Call:
URL/app/atmosphere/rpc?clientId=62831CFA-96E1-46E9-BFC8-AD3A02B59A79&eventType=dashboardnotification&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=aab2c72d-9fbd-4cc6-a9a2-8c9191f19a4c&X-Atmosphere-Framework=3.0.0-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=long-polling&Content-Type=text%2Fx-gwt-rpc%3B%20charset%3DUTF-8&X-atmo-protocol=true&_=1730362560535

Client code:
@Bean
   public ServletRegistrationBean<AtmosphereServlet> atmosphereServlet() throws ServletException {
      AtmosphereServlet atmosphereServlet = new AtmosphereServlet();
      atmosphereServlet.framework().addAtmosphereHandler("/app/atmosphere/rpc", new GwtRpcAtmosphereHandler(),
         Arrays.asList(new GwtRpcInterceptor(),
            // Proxies and firewalls can sometimes close inactive connections. To prevent them from closing a connection
            // when
            // using streaming, server side events or websocket transport, you can install an heartbeat
            // AtmosphereInterceptor
            // that will write whitespace after 60 seconds of inactivity, keeping the connection active.
            new HeartbeatInterceptor()));
      // Preventing Out Of Memory
      // Using shareable ExecutorServices
      // If your application creates a lot of Broadcasters, you may experience some Out Of Memory error because too many
      // instances of ExecutorServices have been created, e.g number of broadcaster * 3. If that's the case, you can
      // configure Atmosphere to share ExecutorServices amongst Broadcasters.
      atmosphereServlet.framework().addInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.BROADCASTER_SHARABLE_THREAD_POOLS, "true");
      // Configuring the maximum threads used by a Broadcaster.
      // To configure the maximum threads created by the Broadcaster of the message delivery
      atmosphereServlet.framework()
         .addInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.BROADCASTER_MESSAGE_PROCESSING_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE, "10");
      atmosphereServlet.framework()
         .addInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.BROADCASTER_ASYNC_WRITE_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE, "10");
      // The heartbeat frequency, in seconds.
      // Default: 60
      atmosphereServlet.framework().addInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS, "60");
      atmosphereServlet.framework().addInitParameter(ApplicationConfig.CLIENT_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS, "60");
      
      ServletRegistrationBean<AtmosphereServlet> servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<AtmosphereServlet>(
         atmosphereServlet,
         "/app/atmosphere/*");
      servletRegistrationBean.setName("AtmosphereServlet");
      servletRegistrationBean.setAsyncSupported(true);
      servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      
      return servletRegistrationBean;
   }

I also found this error in the browser console, but it is only shown once. Can it be depending to this problem?
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject$
SEVERE: Failed to deserialize message: b07f16d9-82a2-447e-90c8-790d53bbf3d1|60000|X|
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at Unknown.xi(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.new Dsc(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.Tvd(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.wMg(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.eval(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.HX(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.KX(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.eval(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.m(https://mes-dev.web.porsche.de/axm/js/atmosphere-3.0.0.min.js)
    at Unknown.al(https://mes-dev.web.porsche.de/axm/js/atmosphere-3.0.0.min.js)
    at Unknown.ai(https://mes-dev.web.porsche.de/axm/js/atmosphere-3.0.0.min.js)
    at Unknown.aK.onreadystatechange(https://mes-dev.web.porsche.de/axm/js/atmosphere-3.0.0.min.js)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at Unknown.ii(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.wi(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.zi(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.apg(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.new bqg(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.BQ(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.Hyc(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.Tvd(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.wMg(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.eval(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.HX(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.KX(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.eval(app-0.js)
    at Unknown.m(https://mes-dev.web.porsche.de/axm/js/atmosphere-3.0.0.min.js)
    at Unknown.al(https://mes-dev.web.porsche.de/axm/js/atmosphere-3.0.0.min.js)
    at Unknown.ai(https://mes-dev.web.porsche.de/axm/js/atmosphere-3.0.0.min.js)
    at Unknown.aK.onreadystatechange(https://mes-dev.web.porsche.de/axm/js/atmosphere-3.0.0.min.js)


Are you sure the error message only appears once, and that it isn't repeating, with a number (usually in red) next to it showing how many times that log message has repeated?
It looks like the payload being sent to the client seems to be invalid - it should not be sent as empty, and the client is trying to read parts of the payload, and isn't expecting it to be empty. Can you examine the headers of the responses to see if your guess about an auth issue has any evidence there? What about server logs?
